# How to choose default output port (boot screen) in a nvidia card?

Tags: boot, nvidia, hdmi, gpu-driver

I have a NVida card and binary drivers. I have my monitor connected at the vga port and the TV at the HDMI port. When the computer boots, the grub menu and sometimes the login screen goes to the TV (HDMI output).

How do I select the default video output to be the VGA port?

Edit: The Dell logo also goes to the HDMI port, also the Grub menu and boot messages. Just when the login screen appears, it uses my configured main display. I've recently added the NVidia Card. Ubuntu was installed using an onboard Intel chipset.

Comment: Loginscreen, just move your mouse across to the other one.

Comment: grub/boot menu -> TV

Comment: @Tim: the problem is that the TV faces the sofa, not may chair. I just see the back of it.

Comment: @Hannu: is it possible to configure the grub menu?

Comment: [This](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/126625) might one option to try...

Answer (score 2):

Launch `nvidia-settings` either from a Terminal or from the Dash,
then find and click `X Server Display Configuration` *(the second line in the left side panel for me)*...

Click on the VGA monitor in the right side panel that appears,
then look below for `[ ] Make this be the primary display for the X screen`
- make that box contain a tick -> `[v]`,
then click <kbd>Save to X Configuration File</kbd> and <kbd>Quit</kbd>

Does that make any difference?

*FWIW: I have the X login prompt come up on the upper of the right side displays, despite of the above. I'd like to have that prompt in front of me instead. <- Yes, that is a "mee too!". I don't see the grub menu elsewhere than on the left side display though  :-I*
*And yes, that is a total of four displays.*

Comment: Good answer, but the boot menu appear before the driver loads. Now I perceived that even the Dell logo appears at the TV Screen.